# How to get current location using google-apps-scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I would like to get from google-apps-scripts gmail addon the user current location. I couldn't manage to run a method from HtmlService within a card.

Is there a way to include html to a card or alternatively get geolocation within a card?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/access-user-locale

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I was thinking more in line of longitude, latitude

Comment: Apps Script runs on a remote Google server, not the client device

Comment: I get that, but they can generate HTML that get the location, no?

Comment: Sure. They don't give add-on developers any way to access privileged information like user location though. File a feature request in Google's public Gmail add-on issue tracker. Note that every user has the right to deny their browser the location permission, so you should be ready to handle this missing information anyway. If you want to display route or distance information based on information in an email, offer a click action that opens Google Maps in directions mode, to the location of interest. If the user wants that info, then they can get it.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128816710

Comment: Even if you could get the users location.  It might not be the correct one if they're on a vpn.